# AngularJS $q.all, trigger regardless of error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Is there a way to trigger $q.all regardless if the promises returned back an error?

I'm trying to perform multiple $http.post requests, POSTing values from text fields inputted by the user.  The back end (Django REST framework) has a value checker we implemented, so if the value being POSTed is different from what's expected (ie, a string is submitted where an integer is expected) a 400 status will return, which in turn causes $q.all to not trigger, which is causing many different errors in my application.

```
//Beginning of for loop, getting values in text fields, setting
//up other things I'm not sure are really relevant here.

            var writeRes = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/' + api_prefix + '/values/',
                data: out_data, //defined elsewhere, not relevent here.
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json','X-CSRFToken': $scope.valueForm.csrf_token,'Accept': 'application/json;data=verbose' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
                });

            saved.push(writeRes);
            //array defined at beginning of for loop

            writeRes.success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                $scope.scope.param_values.push(data.id);
                //array of IDs relevant to the REST framework.
            });
            error(function(status){
                //not sure what to do here.
            });
        }

    }

    $q.all(saved).then(function() { //perform other PATCH, DELETE, GET tasks }
```

The proper values are being POSTed, but if there is an error, the post processing in $q.all does not get triggered, which causes a lot of issues when the page refreshes.

Is there any way that $q.all can be triggered regardless of errors?

I apologize if my questions seem elusive, I really don't know much about front-end development and feel like I'm running in circles with this project.

Comment: Not sure if the suggestion would apply, but you could explicitly reject the promise objects on your client side after some arbitrary time out to make `$q.all` return promptly.

Comment: That is expected... `$q.all` success will get triggered only when all of the promises are resolved. You could do this way `var writeRes = $http(...).then(successHandlerReturnData, errorHandlerDosomethingWItherrorandreturndataornull)` and push this onto the array..' This way you are not rejecting the promise from within the error block and `$q.all` will always go to success block.

Comment: I believe that `$q.all` is a promise in itself so you should be able to replicate what you need in the second parameter function. `$q.all(saved).then(successFn, errorFn)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will look in to these options!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the `$q.reject()` method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#reject) shows how you can "catch" the rejection callback and recover from it.

In this case you can just return a new value from the rejection function and `$q` will treat the promise as being resolved:

```
writeRes.then(function(data, status, headers, config){
    $scope.scope.param_values.push(data.id);
    //array of IDs relevant to the REST framework.
}, function(error){
    // handle the error and recover
    return true;
});
```

Comment: This did not work right away, but I will keep playing with this, because this seems to me like a step in the right direction.